# How to deal with URI request parameter in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, uri

I am working with AWS API gateway and some of the API require URI request parameter ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPolicy.html)). Is that I can simply call it by below URL? Any setting I need to be done in API gateway?
`https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.awsregion.amazonaws.com/my_stage/my_resource/target-policies/my_policy_name`

Also what does Pattern: [\w+=,.@-]+ mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your doubt 100%.

The link you provided is related to attach a policy on API Gateway.

The pattern your ask is the allowed characters for policy name.

If you question is about get URI parameters, for example via querystring, you can just post it to your API Gateway and use it on your method integration.